# Wordpress MySQL database query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, service, irc

I am in the process of setting up a wordpress website that connects to a relay chatroom with an integrated login system, I have connected the database which is working fine however its not allowing the authentication for the users to happen.

The query that i am running in the configuration is:

```
"SELECT `user_email` AS `email` FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_login` = @a@ AND `user_pass` = MD5(@p@)"
```

What i am wanting to do is basically have the query check that the user_login exists and then authenticates with the password.

The error that i am currently receiving is as follows:

```
COMMAND: username@host.host used IDENTIFY and failed to identify to nonexistent account username
```

This is totally puzzling me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress doesn't use MD5. So your query is wrong. You can't do it with MySQL only.  But you can do it with PHP.

Here is one simple way to achieve it:

Step 1:
Grab class-phpass.php file from WordPress installation (wp-includes directory) and paste it to the neighbour to your request sender file. And use this piece of code there:

```
    require_once("class-phpass.php");
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
    $password='open_password_to_check_here';
    $hashed_password='hashed_password_from_mysql'; //select user_pass from wp_users where user_login=@a@;
    $result=$wp_hasher->CheckPassword($password,$hashed_password));
    //if result is true, then auth is OK.
```

Alternatively (and the best way) you can use WP REST API, which contains auth process.